# disable struts anchor link after request send to the action

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, struts2

I want to disable the anchor tag after i send the action for prevent user clicks again the anchor link while the request process in server side for some time and return the response.

There is a onclick event also in my s:a becuase i need to get the confirmation also from the user.

Below is how my sturts anchor tag looks like,

```
<s:a id="tokenReGen" disabled= "true" theme="encrypted" href="%{url}" onclick="return confirmTokenRegenerateAndPreventClick()"><img src="../image//Info.png"  border="0"/></s:a>
```

What i initially thought of doing was some thing like below. But the problem here is then even for the first time my action would not trigger because i set the href to #. Can please tell me a solution where i can disable the anchor link after the request send to the action class.

```
function confirmTokenRegenerateAndPreventClick(){

        var isConfirm = confirmTokenRegenerate();
        if(isConfirm){
            $('#tokenReGen').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
            document.getElementById('tokenReGen').href = '#';
        }

        return isConfirm;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<script>
     var clicked=false;

     function confirmTokenRegenerateAndPreventClick(){
        if(!clicked){
            clicked=true;
            return clicked;
        }
        return false;
     }
```